# telegram bot ,How to make bigger buttons with emoj caption

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I'm trying to make this kind of inlineKeyboardButtons :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHSTA.png

Which is bigger in width and has emojis inside it.
How can I do so ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use code of emoji in button caption. For getting codes take a look at [this list](http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html#1f913).
If you want bigger width then only one element should be declared in the  array of `InlineKeyboardButton` objects.

Comment: could you give me an example of bigger width Button.I tried one element of InlineKeyboardButton objects but the width of the button doesn't change .

Comment: @j.hamid, what you mean by "width"? Now from your words I can see you mean hight. Isn't it?

Comment: no I mean width .I want the buttons to take the whole screen and be bigger

Answer (score 0):

That is a [inline keyboard](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardmarkup) where the [button](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton) text contains an emoji.